# how to show all the values on x-axis in amcharts

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I want to show the exact total that a user has achieved like this:

[image]

Here is how I generate the chart. Is there any way to show the exact value, if I can show all the values in x-axis that wil work fine too.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"theme": "light",
"type": "serial",
"dataProvider": [
{
    "year": "WORK--------------------",
    "income":0
},
{
    "year": "Well",
    "income": <?=$final1?>
}, {
    "year":  "Opportunity-oriented",
    "income": <?=$final2?>
}, {
    "year": "Relationship-driven",
    "income": <?=$final3?>
}, {
    "year": "Kind",
    "income": <?=$final4?>
}, 
{
    "year": "",
    "income": 0
}, 
{
    "year": "SMART-------------------",
    "income":0
},

        {
    "year": "Successful",
    "income":<?=$final5?>
},
 {
    "year": "Managerial",
    "income": <?=$final6?>
},
 {
    "year": "Action-oriented",
    "income":<?=$final7?>
},
 {
    "year": "Resilient",
    "income": <?=$final8?>
},
{
    "year": "Tenacious",
    "income": <?=$final9?>
},

    ],

    "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Work Smart Assessment",
                              "minimum": 0,
"maximum": 5

}],
"graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "Income in [[category]]:[[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "title": "Income",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "income",
    "colorField": "color"
}],
"depth3D": 0,
"angle": 30,
"rotate": true,
"categoryField": "year",
"categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "fillAlpha": 0.05,
    "position": "left"
},
"export": {
    "enabled": true
 }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.

1) You can set [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelText) to `"[[value]]"` in your graph to display the total on top of the column, however you can't make it display all the way at the edge like in your screenshot. You might also want to set [`showAllValueLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showAllValueLabels) to true in case your value is close to the end of the X-axis so that you can force it to be visible. This is the easiest option as the values are rendered automatically by the chart:

```
graphs: [{
  // ...
  labelText: "[[value]]"
  showAllValueLabels: true,
  // ...
}]
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "dataProvider": [{
      "year": "WORK--------------------",
      "income": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "Well",
      "income": 1.0
    }, {
      "year": "Opportunity-oriented",
      "income": 2.0
    }, {
      "year": "Relationship-driven",
      "income": 3.0
    }, {
      "year": "Kind",
      "income": 4.0
    },
    {
      "year": "",
      "income": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "SMART-------------------",
      "income": 0
    },

    {
      "year": "Successful",
      "income": 4.8
    },
    {
      "year": "Managerial",
      "income": 3.8
    },
    {
      "year": "Action-oriented",
      "income": 2.5
    },
    {
      "year": "Resilient",
      "income": 1.3
    },
    {
      "year": "Tenacious",
      "income": 1.8
    },

  ],

  "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Work Smart Assessment",
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 5

  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "Income in [[category]]:[[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "title": "Income",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "income",
    "labelText": "[[value]]",
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "colorField": "color"
  }],
  "depth3D": 0,
  "angle": 30,
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "fillAlpha": 0.05,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css">
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

2) If you really need the labels to show up on the right hand side, you can use [`guides`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide), but you'll need to generate each label yourself in your code. You'll also need to set a `marginRight` in your chart to account for the labels.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "marginRight": 50, //adjust as needed
  "guides": [{
      "category": "Well",
      "label": "1.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "category": "Opportunity-oriented",
      "label": "2.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    }, 
  // .. etc
  ],
});
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "marginRight": 50,
  "guides": [{
      "category": "Well",
      "label": "1.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "category": "Opportunity-oriented",
      "label": "2.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "category": "Relationship-driven",
      "label": "3.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    }, {
      "category": "Kind",
      "label": "4.0",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
    {
      "category": "Successful",
      "label": "4.8",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
    {
      "category": "Managerial",
      "label": "3.8",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
    {
      "category": "Action-oriented",
      "label": "2.5",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
    {
      "category": "Resilient",
      "label": "1.3",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
    {
      "category": "Tenacious",
      "label": "1.8",
      "lineAlpha": 0,
      "tickLength": 0,
      "boldLabel": true,
      "position": "right"
    },
  ],
  "dataProvider": [{
      "year": "WORK--------------------",
      "income": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "Well",
      "income": 1.0
    }, {
      "year": "Opportunity-oriented",
      "income": 2.0
    }, {
      "year": "Relationship-driven",
      "income": 3.0
    }, {
      "year": "Kind",
      "income": 4.0
    },
    {
      "year": "",
      "income": 0
    },
    {
      "year": "SMART-------------------",
      "income": 0
    },

    {
      "year": "Successful",
      "income": 4.8
    },
    {
      "year": "Managerial",
      "income": 3.8
    },
    {
      "year": "Action-oriented",
      "income": 2.5
    },
    {
      "year": "Resilient",
      "income": 1.3
    },
    {
      "year": "Tenacious",
      "income": 1.8
    },

  ],

  "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Work Smart Assessment",
    "minimum": 0,
    "maximum": 5

  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "Income in [[category]]:[[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "title": "Income",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "income",
    "colorField": "color"
  }],
  "depth3D": 0,
  "angle": 30,
  "rotate": true,
  "categoryField": "year",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "fillAlpha": 0.05,
    "position": "left"
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css">
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: labelText: "[[value]]"
  showAllValueLabels: true, <--this worked